# python error on windows: from OpenGL import GL

Tags: python, windows, opengl

I have installed pyOpenGL on python3.5 64bit on windows, however when I run

```
>>> from OpenGL import GL
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\win32.py", line 25, in GL
ctypes.windll, 'opengl32', mode = ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\ctypesloader.py", line 45, in loadLibrary
return dllType( name, mode )
File "C:\Python35\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GL\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from OpenGL import error as _error
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\error.py", line 12, in <module>
from OpenGL import platform, _configflags
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
_load()
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\__init__.py", line 32, in _load
plugin.install(globals())
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 92, in install
namespace[ name ] = getattr(self,name,None)
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 14, in __get__
value = self.fget( obj )
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\win32.py", line 103, in GetCurrentContext
wglGetCurrentContext = self.GL.wglGetCurrentContext
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 14, in __get__
value = self.fget( obj )
File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\win32.py", line 28, in GL
raise ImportError("Unable to load OpenGL library", *err.args)
ImportError: ('Unable to load OpenGL library', 8, '%1 is not a valid Win32 application', None, 193, None, 'C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\opengl32.dll', 'C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\opengl32.dll')
```

I understand it tried to load a 64 bit opengl32.dll as a Win32 application, however, I'm running on python 3.5 64bit, how could I end up trying to linking with a Win32 application?

Could anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you install PyOpenGL? The problem is definitely in a 32-biot/64-bit mismatch between Python and the native C extensions of PyOpenGL. So somethying in that process has led to you inadvertently installing the 32-bit PyOpenGL version.

Comment: @Bartvbl, Thanks for you reply. I installed the PyOpenGL using pip: pip3 install PyOpenGL and I get no error.